# In what situations is Abigail useful?

Tags: dont-starve

I just started playing as Wendy for the first time and I noticed that Abigail doesn't provide much help when battling a Treeguard. She can take only a few hits and then she drops her flower.

When running away from werepigs, I dropped the flower and tried to kill one werepig out of three, but I was overwhelmed by then.

In what situations is Abigail most useful? How can I use her to shift enemies' attention quickly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Abigail's attack is relatively weak but it affects all enemies near her. She's not very good at fighting single, larger enemies (though pretty much anything that tries to fight a tree without kiting it will die). She is, however, extremely effective against groups of smaller enemies such as spider dens.

Once summoned, Abigail will remain until killed. This means you can summon her outside of combat by killing a rabbit or other small creature and have her with you when the fight starts. It's much easier than trying to summon her while fighting/running for your life.

Comment: I found out that she's especially effective for farming spiders in desert rock valleys. She can handle a very large group at least once with no problem. After that, she needs time to regenerate health, or the spiders will overwhelm Abigail, if you decide to attack again too soon.